# LinkedList: Removing the duplicates

Tags: java, data-structures

I know this is a duplicate problem but my question is different.
Help me to understand few lines of this code.
It removes duplicate nodes from a single linked list.

```
public class DeleteDuplicates {

    static void deleteDups(LinkedListNode n) {
        Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
        LinkedListNode previous = null;
        while(n!=null) {
            if(table.containsKey(n.data)) {
                previous.next = n.next;
            } else {
                table.put(n.data, true);
                previous = n;
            }
            System.out.println(n.next.data);
            n = n.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedListNode node_1 = new LinkedListNode("first");        
        LinkedListNode node_2 = new LinkedListNode("second");
        node_1.next = node_2;
        LinkedListNode node_3 = new LinkedListNode("third");
        node_2.next = node_3;
        LinkedListNode node_4 = new LinkedListNode("second");
        node_3.next = node_4;

        LinkedListNode  current = node_1;
        deleteDups(current);
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.println(current.data);
            current = current.next;
        }

    }

}
```

Questions I have are:

1. How come LinkedList `n` is skipping the duplicate node? I didn't understand the use of `previous` node and how it is helping in skipping the duplicate node.
2. How important is the use of `Hashtable`? Can I use any other collection for example `HashSet`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have good answers to your question 2, so I'll just concentrate on question 1 (really you should only ask 1 question in each post, by the way).  This is how the removal of the duplicate works:

In each iteration through your loop, `previous` holds a reference to the node in the list before the node `n`.  So, when `n` is set to your `node_4`, `previous` is set to `node_3`.  Therefore, `previous.next = n.next` is equivalent to `node_3.next = node_4.next`, which because you don't set a value for `node_4.next` is equivalent to `node_3.next = null`, which has the effect of making `node_3` the last node in the list, thus removing `node_4` from the list.

If, instead of `node_4` being the duplicate, it was `node_3` that was duplicated, then `previous` would be `node_2`, `n` would be `node_3` and the change made would be equivalent to `node_2.next = node_3.next`, which is to say `node_2.next = node_4` or in plain English, "make the next node after node_2 be node_4", effectively removing `node_3` from the list.

Answer (score 0):

1) LinkedList is not skipping the duplicate node, it is being mapped out - next is pointed to the entry after the duplicate.
2) Think `LinkedList` allows duplicates, but `Hashtable` does not -> make your conclusion from this

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on Answer 1? How does `previous.next = n.next;` helps to map out duplicate node?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any data structure you like for detecting duplicates.

From an implementation point of view, hashes are nice because they take (amortized) constant time to determine whether or not a particular element is a duplicate.

From an API point of view, the `Collection.Set` interface is nice because it guarantees no duplicate items.

So your idea of using a `HashSet` seems very intuitive, especially because you're only interested in duplicate keys, without regard for the actual node object.

Comment: Agreed - a HashSet would be a better way of doing this, because it is clearer what you're trying to do.  Hashtables are for associating keys to values, HashSets are for keeping a collection of items so you can quickly tell whether a new item is already in the collection.